# SQL Server IN() function not allowing a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table in SQL Server, but when I put a select statement in the `IN` function, SQL Server highlights the select word as an error is it wrong to use a select statement in an `IN()` function?

```
SELECT * 
FROM sourcetabel1
PIVOT
    (AVG(Amount) 
         FOR SalaryTypeName IN (SELECT SalaryName 
                                FROM table2) AS pvt
```

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design  does not support macro substitution.   This would require Dynamic SQL or a literal list like ( [Col1],[Col2],...  )

Comment: Tested in Access. Doesn't error but the embedded SQL statement is treated like a single string item so end up with a field name of `[SELECT SalaryName FROM table2]` and no data in that column.